# Linear Differential Equations with variable coefficients and laplace Transform..

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is Laplace Transform useful in solving linear differential equations if the coefficients are not constant?

Comment: Sometimes, if you're up to integrating by parts a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Laplace Transform is occasionally useful in solving linear differential equations with variable coefficients.

For example the differential equation $$xy''-xy'+y=5$$ will transform to $$ Y'(s)+(\frac {2}{s}) Y(s)= \frac {5}{s^2}$$ which is a first order linear equation.